# Сборка статической библиотеки из Python кода

Tags: c++, python

Существует необходимость использования Python кода в С++ проекте со следующим требованием: собранный .exe должен быть полностью standalone (т.е. должна быть возможность успешно запустить его  и получить результаты работы на виртуальной машине с голой windows 10, без интерпретатора и чего либо дополнительно установленного).

Смотрел в сторону Boost.Python и Cython, но насколько я понял, они не предоставят мне необходимого функционала. Как по мне, решением здесь будет сборка Python кода в статическую библиотеку, с последующей линковкой ее в С++ проект.

Каким образом можно это реализовать?

Comment: для .exe идeально годится `pyinstaller`, ставитe флаги -F и -w, получаeтe отстраннeнный файл, запускаeмый на голой виндe

Comment: только pyinstaller это самараспаковывающийся архив с кучей библиотек и питонским кодом. статическую линковку из стандартного питона получить нельзя

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал необходимый функционал с помощью pybind11.

Подробности: 
https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html